# Convert groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object to a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, data-science

I have a dataframe as below:

```
Id | C1 | C2 
---|----|----
 1 | 1  | 12 
 1 | 2  | 15 
 2 | 4  | 20
 2 | 5  | 25
```

I am trying to `groupby` 'Id' and construct a dictionary for each 'Id'

```
df = df.groupby('Id')
dt = df.to_dict()
```

I get an error:

> AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'to_dict' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

I am trying to get an output(list of dictionaries) as:

```
{Id: 1: {C1: [1, 2], 
     C2: [12, 15]},

Id: 2: {C1: [4, 5],
     C2: [20, 25]}
}
```

Comment: You need to apply an aggregation function to a groupby. A simple example would be `df.groupby('Id').mean()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [36]: output = {}
In [37]: print(df)
    Id  C1  C2
0   1   1  12
1   1   2  15
2   2   4  20
3   2   5  25

In [38]: columns = set(df.columns.tolist()) - set(['Id'])

In [39]: for key, grouped in df.groupby('Id'):
    ...:     output[key] = {}
    ...:     for col in columns:
    ...:         output[key][col] = grouped[col].tolist()
    ...:         

In [40]: print(output)
{1: {'C2': [12, 15], 'C1': [1, 2]}, 2: {'C2': [20, 25], 'C1': [4, 5]}}
```

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: `{Id: 1: {C1: [1, 2],

     C2: [12, 15]},
Id: 2: {C1: [4, 5],

     C2: [20, 25]}` The dictionary can only contain key and values, Is `Id` a key and what about `1`

Comment: In place of 'Id', can have the value of 'Id'. For example, Id=1 or Id=2

Comment: @Raj: Is this what you are looking for